# RestTemplate postForEntity returns null response but Postman gives expected body

Tags: java, resttemplate

I have a series of web requests which has Basic Authorization. The first request is a GET and works as expected but the next in line is a POST and returns null body. The same request when executed in Postman returns json response body which is the expected. I do not understand what i miss. My code:

```
            String plainCreds = username+":"+password;
            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
            
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange( requestURLGetToken, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
            String token = obj.getJSONObject("token").getString("value");
            
            headers.add("TOKEN", token);             
            String body = "json string";            
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setConnection("keep-alive");
            var requestExpand = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
            var responseExpand = restTemplate.postForEntity(requestURLPostToken, requestExpand, String.class);
```

The last request using `postForEntity` return a null body. Can anybody advise on what could be the possible issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is the POST request working in postman? Which query are you using with postman? Are you sure that requestURLPostToken is valid and does listen for your request?

Comment: @Milgo  Yes its working perfectly in Postman. I get a 200 for my request for postForEntity but no response body. While debugging i took the contents for request and executed the Postman with the same and got the results.

Comment: when  you are making a post call, you don't need to pass both `TOKEN` and `Authorization` in headers. you should only pass `token`

Comment: Please add your postman query. It can't be the same as in this code.

Comment: @Pramod so you mean to add only the token in the header, then i get a 400: "error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid, expired or missing authenticated session. New service ticket required"

Comment: So i have got it working by creating a new headers and adding the token and authorization for the request. Thanks for the replies.